# After doing group project React Native and React Native Expo and how merging them in

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, react-native, mobile-application

What are the main differences between React Native and React Native Expo? Are there any limitations or advantages of using one over the other?
How can we handle the project structure when integrating both React Native and React Native Expo components? Are there any considerations or best practices we should follow?
Are there any compatibility issues or conflicts that we need to be aware of when combining React Native and React Native Expo code in the same project?
Are there any tools or libraries available to help with the integration and merging process? Any recommended resources or tutorials for achieving this?
What are some common strategies or approaches that teams have successfully used to collaborate on projects when working with both React Native and React Native Expo?

How it can be done without get error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.